# Accelerating charges

Tags: electromagnetism, radiation

Considering the fact that accelerating charges radiate, thereby losing energy and magnets are made up of tiny dipoles that consist of spinning electrons, why doesn't the magnet radiate and eventually lose it's magnetic field, since the rotating electrons that make up the magnet are accelerating?

Comment: because electrons are point-like and while they do possess spin that does not mean that they are *spinning*.

Comment: In classical EM, a finite-radius spinning charged sphere has a static field and doesn’t radiate, despite the fact that the charges are accelerating. Similarly, a loop of current-carrying wire doesn’t radiate if the current is constant. So there is no reason to think that an electron with quantum-mechanical spin should radiate.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the reasons quantum mechanics had to be invented. The [Bohr model](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/bohrcn.html) , in order to avoid the similar question ,"why electrons do not fall on the nucleus radiating away their energy according to the classical electrodynamics rules" imposes an ad hoc quantization of angular momentum. The electron had to stay in a quantized  orbit. That explained the observed atomic spectra, but was not  really a theory.

Schrodinger's equation and the theory of quantum mechanics with its [postulates,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) reproduced the Bohr model successes but gave a mathematical handle in modeling and predicting particle and atomic and molecular situations.

The tiny dipoles are in bound states and obey quantum mechanical equations and do not radiate away their energy.